# Checking for duplicated data in Java array list

Tags: java

I am writing a basic library app which uses an arraylist of books in its book repository class.

I can add books to the list using a books.add(new book(...))  command as shown below.

However, is there a way I can notify the user if they try adding a book ISBN which already exists?

```
    // constructor
    public Book(String isbn, String title, String author, String genre, int year, int quantity, int numCheckedOut) {
        super();
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.year = year;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.numCheckedOut = numCheckedOut;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    
    public boolean checkOut() {
        if (numCheckedOut >= quantity) {
            return false;
        }
        numCheckedOut++;
        return true;
    }
    
    public boolean checkIn() {
        if (numCheckedOut <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        numCheckedOut--;
        return true;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public int getNumCheckedOut() {
        return numCheckedOut;
    }
}
```

```
public class BookRepository {
    
    private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public BookRepository() {
        books.add(new Book("1", "To Kill a Mockingbird", "Harper Lee", "Fiction", 1960, 4, 0));
}
```

Comment: `if (books.stream().filter(o -> o.getIsbn().equals(testIsbn)).findFirst().isPresent()) { /* warn user */ } else { /*  add book to books */ }`

Comment: Or use a set at first place (not a list).

Comment: For @Seelenvirtuose's suggestion to work, your Book class would need to override both the equals and hashCode method (which it should be doing regardless), using the ISBN number as its sole test of equality and the sole source of the hashCode.